# Append Json to div

Tags: jquery, json, html, append

Hello i have result in json format and i want to append it to html div. the json looks like:

```
jsonp1373893536648([{
    "MAXCHILDREN": 1,
    "PICTURE": "3AE30747-0956-0F6C-F6F4D6FC13243BDF.jpg",
    "MAXPERSONS": 3,
    "RATEINCLUDE": 2,
}, {
    "MAXCHILDREN": 1,
    "PICTURE": "3AF1F0ED-01DC-32C8-C663F39A1B430F89.jpg",
    "MAXPERSONS": 3,
    "RATEINCLUDE": 2,
}, {
    "MAXCHILDREN": 3,
    "PICTURE": "3AF6A412-CB40-3B77-C777273F5378345A.jpg",
    "MAXPERSONS": 3,
    "RATEINCLUDE": 2,
}, {
    "MAXCHILDREN": 1,
    "PICTURE": "3AFC9046-92F4-DBB7-93E5D7EF8A9AB831.jpg",
    "MAXPERSONS": 3,
    "RATEINCLUDE": 2,
}])
```

now i need for example to do something like this:

```
jQuery(response_container).append('<div class="maxchildren">MAXCHILDREN: ' + MAXCHILDREN + '</div>');
jQuery(response_container).append('<div class="pic">PICTURE: ' + PICTURE+ '</div>'); ...
```

for each MAXCHILDREN, PICTURE, MAXPERSONS, RATEINCLUDE.
please any help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    jQuery(response_container).append('<div class="maxchildren">MAXCHILDREN: ' + result[i].MAXCHILDREN+ '</div>');   
    jQuery(response_container).append('<div class="pic">PICTURE: ' + result[i].PICTURE+ '</div>');
...
}
```

`result` is the name of the json object when you receive it. It depends on you, the name that you've given it. 
The object you have is an array of json objects, so you access every object by `result[i]`. You access every element of the json object of the array by `result[i].NAME_OF_KEY` (i.e `result[i].MAXCHILDREN`) or `result[i]['NAME_OF_KEY']` (i.e `result[i]['MAXCHILDREN']`).

Answer (score 4):

Try with, assuming data is the response you are talking about:

```
var a = data, b = 0;

while( b < a.length ){

    $('<div/>',{

         'class' : 'maxchildren',
         'text' : 'MAXCHILDREN: ' + a[ b ].MAXCHILDREN

    }).appendTo( response_container );

    $('<div/>',{

         'class' : 'pic',
         'text' : 'PICTURE: ' + a[ b ].PICTURE

    }).appendTo( response_container );

    b++;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Didn't know of this method adding the text and attributes as a json. @pey22 you should upvote too since this post was useful for you.